Getting Error: Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.) when trying to make a post request to Django view
I am trying to create a (chrome extension + Django) password manager that will read input boxes from forms and on clicking submit it will make a POST request to the Django view with the data which will then get stored on to the postgresql database. (Keep in mind, this is only a personal project.)
But on every request, I get the error: Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.). Even though I see csrftoken cookie under the Applications tab in inspect. I am passing the csrf token along with the request so I can't figure out what the error is.
I have tried getting the csrf token from cookies using Cookies.get('csrftoken') and also setting the csrf token cookie after fetching it from Django as well.
This is what my view looks like in Django :
@ensure_csrf_cookie
def add(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        website = request.POST['website']
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = request.user
        encryptedPass = cryptography.crypto(password)
        credentials = Credentials.objects.create(email=username, password=encryptedPass)
        if Website.objects.filter(user = user.id).filter(name=website).exists():
            website_obj = Website.objects.filter(user = user.id).filter(name=website)
            # print(website_obj[0].credentials)
            website_obj[0].credentials.add(credentials)
        else:
            website_obj = Website.objects.create(user=user, name=website)
            website_obj.credentials.add(credentials) 
        if request.headers.get('X-Requested-With') == 'XMLHttpRequest': 
            return JsonResponse({'message':'Credentials Add'})      
        return redirect('add')
    return render(request,'add.html')

This is the view where I pass the csrf token to the chrome extension:
@ensure_csrf_cookie
def get_csrf_token(request):
    return JsonResponse({'csrfToken': django.middleware.csrf.get_token(request)})

I have tried everything in my settings.py:
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'corsheaders',
    'password_manager_app'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True

CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ["*"]
CSRF_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = ["*"]
CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = "*"

I am making the post request using axios in my content-script.js:
export async function getCsrfToken(){
  const axios = require('axios')
  let token;
  const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/get-csrf-token',{withCredentials:true}).then((response)=>{
    console.log(response.data.csrfToken)
    token = response.data.csrfToken
  })
  return token
}

export async function axiosaddCredentialsToDatabase(email,password,url){
  const token = await getCsrfToken()
  const axios = require('axios')
  axios.post('http://localhost:8000/add',{email,password,url},{
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'X-CSRFToken': token,
      'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    },
    withCredentials:true
  }).then((response)=>{
    console.log(response)
  })
}

I would appreciate any input. Thanks in advance :)

Put breakpoints in axiosaddCredentialsToDatabase and getCsrfToken and see if the token actually gets set (because the error message implies that the server never received a token). Also, can you try and get the token from the csrftoken cookie, as described in the docs?

@CoffeeBasedLifeform, on checking the network tab, I can see that the token is being placed in the headers successfully.
And also, I have implemented token = Cookie.get('csrftoken) || getTokenFromDjango()
but I still get the same error

Your site should have a csrftoken cookie (that's the whole point of the ensure_csrf_cookie decorator). Try using only that cookie, as described in the docs (make double sure you haven't made a typo and have read it correctly). Start your dev server in debug mode, put a breakpoint in django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware._check_token,  and check that the secret matches the token in the cookie.

That is because somehow the token is not being validated.
Also, one should not send a request just to retrieve this token, the famework middleware will set it as cookie, so you just need to retrieve it. Else, the server would be overloaded with token requests (in a real world environment).
here is a minimal example:
const getCookie = (name) => {
  let cookieValue = null;
  if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== "") {
    const cookies = document.cookie.split(";");
    for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
      const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
      if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === name + "=") {
        cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return cookieValue;
};

const csrftoken = getCookie("csrftoken");
const payload = {
  email: "john.doe@example.com",
  password: "supersecret",
  url: "https://example.com"
};
const headers = {
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken,
};

const sendRequest = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post("/add/", payload, { headers });
    console.log(response.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

sendRequest();

views.py
@ensure_csrf_cookie
def add(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        data = json.loads(request.body)
        url = data["url"]
        email = data["email"]
        password = data["password"]
        # Do your thing
        ...
        return JsonResponse({"message": "Credentials Add"})

    return render(request, "add.html")


getCookie returns null for me. Seems like csrftoken cookie is not being set for some reason eventhough I have added the ensure_csrf_cookie method decorator

In the answer your provided, the cookie is only set after the fetch, correct? (Because the Django view we are trying to POST to is the one setting the cookie?) So doesn't it make sense getCookie returning null?

@MuhaAllAmeen The csrf cookie is created by django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware, ensure it is set in your settings.py.

The cookie should be set before the fetch request, by the middleware. Then one should retrieve this token from the cookies and set as the header of the POST request. For more detailed info, refer to the documentation

To make sure the cookie is being created, check your website cookies with developer tools. Under Application > Cookies.
